# System.PrivateProfileString Word VBA not working since Office (Word) update version 1910

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some legacy code that uses the Microsoft Word VBA System.PrivateProfileString to read a DWORD entry in the Windows registry.  In the past, it would return proper values for String and DWORD registry entries.  Now, after a Office 365 update to version 1910, when reading a DWORD value it is inserting a leading character (possible "null" or some "random" character)  This of course causes the validation of the registry key in following code to fail.

Here is a sample

```
key = System.PrivateProfileString("", "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\Microsoft Outlook", "MSIInstallOnWTS")
MsgBox key
```

The result might be something like (squarebox) []1, or g541

I downgraded my Office 365/Word 2016 to version 1909 build 12130.20272 and the results are as expected.  It works.

rewriting the code to use the Win API directly instead of built in Word System.PrivateProfileString function is the solution but I would like to avoid having to rewrite code and deploy.

Is this a bug, or do I have to re-write all code that is using System.PrivateProfileString?

UPDATE:  After some more investigation, the first character is not random. It is the ASCII character of the DWORD value in the registry.   So, if your DWORD value is 1 you see a square box and a 1.  If you DWORD value is 65 decimal (41 hex) you will see A65, and DWORD of 97(x61) return value is a97.  If the value > 255 then it starts at ascii 65 (A)

Microsoft Word click2run version 1910 (build 12130.20410) also has this problem.

Comment: FWIW I see the same here, but in Windows 10 1903. I would guess it is an error somewhere in Microsoft's Windows or Office code. Here I have no software that's likely to get in the way, such as 3rd party virus checkers, but I have not ruled out all possible Addins. Probably worth reporting via Word's smiley mechanic but I wouldn't expect a response.

Comment: Unclear in the question: Is it always the same character *code*? Or is there a discernible pattern, depending on the value being returned from the Registry key?

Comment: The version of Windows 10 I am using is 1903, but same results in version 1909.  The version of Word I am using is 1910 Build 12130.20344.  I have reported to Microsoft using feedback within Word.  If the return value is 0, there is no leading character. If the return value is 1, the leading character is a square character. If the return value is some other number, then the leading character is some other value.

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft confirmed that this is a bug.**

"the Word engineering team has found the cause of the bug and has implemented a fix for it.  We are targeting the fix for this month's January fork release; final test validation still needs to be completed to confirm this fix can made for that fork.

Thank you again for reporting this bug to us!

Thank you,
The Microsoft Word Team"

It has not yet been fixed in Microsoft Word current version 2001 (build 12430.20288 click-to-run)